# Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject'

Tags: ravendb

I've tried building both .NET 3.5 & 4, using Raven.Client.Lightweight-3.5 version 1.0.0.0.

Getting the above error running the following code:
Any ideas why?

```
public class Test
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080" };
            store.Initialize();

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var test = new Test
                {
                    Name = "test"
                };
                session.Store(test);
                session.SaveChanges();               
            }            
        }
    }
```

Exception trace:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException was unhandled
  Message=Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'Raven.Json.Linq.RavenJObject'.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json.Net35
  StackTrace:
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 417
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 223
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 198
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, Object target) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 552
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 1005
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 842
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 396
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 223
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 208
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 717
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b__0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 663
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionUtils.cs:line 544
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 651
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 446
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 225
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 208
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 120
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 421
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:line 413
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 721
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonConverter[] converters) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 699
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonConverter[] converters) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs:line 668
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectBatch(IEnumerable`1 commandDatas, String operationUrl) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 803
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.<>c__DisplayClass32.<Batch>b__31(String u) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 778
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.TryOperation[T](Func`2 operation, String operationUrl, Boolean avoidThrowing, T& result) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 163
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.ExecuteWithReplication[T](String method, Func`2 operation) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 133
       at Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.Batch(IEnumerable`1 commandDatas) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Connection\ServerClient.cs:line 778
       at Raven.Client.Document.DocumentSession.SaveChanges() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\DocumentSession.cs:line 344
       at RavenHelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\development\Samples\RavenHelloWorld\RavenHelloWorld\Program.cs:line 30
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at one point, I believe it is related to a problem with default credentials that is in build 371.

Try setting Raven/AnonymousAccess to All in the server config and see if it goes away.

Comment: set the value for Anonymous access to 'All' from 'Get' but still no luck.